# Extra option and ng-required

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding an extra option to my list of options with this code:

```
var defaultOption = { id: 0, descrip: 'Select Item Tree...' };
$scope.metaData.itemTrees.splice(0, 0, defaultOption);
```

Now, under certain circumstances I want item tree to be required, so I have

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <select class="form-control" name="itemTree" id="itemTree"
            ng-model="currentSalespoint.iTreeTop" ng-required="salespointMode.needsItemTree"
            ng-options="t.id as t.descrip for t in metaData.itemTrees"></select>
</div>
<div class="field-validation-error">
    <span ng-show="editSalespointGeneral.itemTree.$error.required && editSalespointGeneral.itemTree.$dirty">Item Tree selection is required.</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that 0 should not be a valid choice, e.g. I can not leave 'Select Item Tree' as a selected option. What should I do to make it really required?

If I try to use null instead of 0, I get my error, but then the 'Select ..' disappears and I have empty row instead in my drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of solutions is to define empty item directly in html:

```
<select class="form-control" name="itemTree" id="itemTree"
        ng-model="currentSalespoint.iTreeTop" ng-required="salespointMode.needsItemTree"
        ng-options="t.id as t.descrip for t in metaData.itemTrees">
    <option value="">Select Item Tree...</option>
</select>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7m8YYVz7HNs1OY7hRIF1?p=preview

Comment: This is the original solution I tried but it has a problem. If I try to save that option, it produces an error. Although I've tried that solution before I added ng-required, so I may re-try it again.

Comment: @Naomi: What do you mean by "save that option"?

Comment: I mean that when I pressed the Save button in our form, I got an error (bad request) when I kept that option. However, this was before I added ng-required (and that was the reason I started adding the option in server or JavaScript code). With ng-required I think it will be save to use HTML approach.